# Hypothesis test for aggregate values

Tags: hypothesis-testing

Recall we have two shops that we treat like equal.
We want to increase total income, and we want to evaluate some hypothesis.
The global goal is to find feature, that maximizes total sum of payments, even if a count of sales is decreased, so we interested in total sum of separate sales in a period of time.
Suppose, the size of customer payments is generated by fat-tailed distribution, even without mean (process with Pareto distribution),
so we cannot consider mean or median of two samples, the only thing that needs to be compared is two total sums in the same period of time.

How can we properly organize this type of experiment, where we need to evaluate statistical significance of the change in the aggregate value, not mean, frequency etc?
Is there a generally accepted approach to solving such problems?